# fmod module unsafe for SAFESEH image c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

i'm using VS 2015, im trying to run a project i found on git ([project on git](https://github.com/matthewrdev/Neural-Network)), so i cloned repo and upgraded this project to VS 2015, however while compiling im getting following error:

```
fmodvc.lib(fmod.dll) : error LNK2026: module unsafe for SAFESEH image.
```

i tryed to setting "image safe exception handler" to /SAFESEH:NO, however this did not help.

How can fix this issue and compile this project?